# Stringifying stringified data string

Tags: javascript, backslash, stringify

I try to stringifying options values of a select element. Loop over options works fine. Values of options are stringified strings that taken from some forms data. So when I try to stringify all options values into one string, JSON.stringify adds backslashes just in front of the double quotes. If I post this stringified stringfy string, is it a healthy method to send with post.

second stringifier function below:

```
function secimleriDerle(secimID){
    var sD = nY(secimID);
    var sDizisi = [];

    for (xi = 0,xlen = sD.options.length; xi < xlen; xi++) {
        sDizisi.push(sD.options[xi].value);
    }

    return JSON.stringify(sDizisi); 
}
```

console log that second stringifier function returns:

```
["0","[{\"bankaID\":\"46\",\"makbuzNO\":\"asdasd\",
 \"makbuzTARIHI\":\"12/12/2501\",\"ihracaatYapilacakUlkeID\":\"2\",
 \"ilacIhracADI\":\"asdasd\",\"makbuzTUTAR\":\"202,06\",
 \"makbuzTipDetayDEGERİ\":\"9\"}]"]
```

Comment: why would you stringify a poor array ?

Comment: Hello @user1537158 i have 3 degrees of data collecting. First forms data stringified in options values of a select element, these values stringified again in another (on the fly) object. At the end (while submitting form) all objects values stringified in one string, and posting it.

Comment: I wish to handle all json thing at serverside with php easly, this is the main reason why i try to use stringify. Am i wrong?

Comment: are you sending sDizisi to the server via AJAX ?

Comment: @user1537158 yes, with $.post() , jquerys mothod. But before sending it stringify with same sDizisi like arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is an escape character used by parsers to differentiate between the end of the string quote & a quote in between the string....

So `"\""` simply represents a one character string with value : `"`

Similarly `"\\"` represents a one character string with value : `\`

It has been a standard way to use an [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) for ages & is obviously healthy.

Comment: Thank you @loxxy, so is it a healthy method to send this whole string with post? I can handle it from serverside with php, but i wonder if http make any trouble with it?

Comment: espacially if i send it with jquerys $.post() ?

Comment: http would see the ASCII value `34` (character code of `"`) instead of `\"`